# Serial port programming in iPhone

Tags: iphone, serial-port

Which classes or functions do I have to use to open the serial port and read data from the serial port in Objective c?  If anybody knows, please provide sample code, that will very helpful for me as I am new to Objective c.

Comment: try this link http://devdot.wikispaces.com/Iphone+Serial+Port+Tutorial

Answer (score 1):

You need to become a Made for iPhone member to communicate with external devices via the electrical connector or Bluetooth. See http://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi. You can then use the External Accessory framework (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ExternalAccessory/Reference/ExternalAccessoryFrameworkReference/_index.html).

Another option would be to try to findva means to use wifi through some adapter. This requires no mfi membership.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a private project you can checkout Redpark serial cable for iOS and its SDK http://redpark.com/c2db9.html